# Why the prvalue below in [expr.ref]/2?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

[[expr.ref]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#2):

> For the first option (dot) the first expression shall be a glvalue
>   having complete class type. For the second option (arrow) the first
>   expression shall be a **prvalue** having pointer to complete class type.
>   The expression E1->E2 is converted to the equivalent form (*(E1)).E2;
>   the remainder of [expr.ref] will address only the first option
>   (dot).68 In either case, the id-expression shall name a member of the
>   class or of one of its base classes. [ Note: Because the name of a
>   class is inserted in its class scope (Clause [class]), the name of a
>   class is also considered a nested member of that class.  — end note ]
>   [ Note: [basic.lookup.classref] describes how names are looked up
>   after the . and -> operators.  — end note ]

In the snippet below, `p->f()` is a *postfix-expression* and `p` is an lvalue.

```
struct A{ void f(){} };
A *p = new A;
int main(){
    p->f();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a prvalue is required but a glvalue is given, the glvalue may be converted to a prvalue by *lvalue-to-rvalue conversion* [conv.lval]. Thus prvalues are fairly general and easily obtained.

Comment: [expr]/9: "Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue. "